# How to use the command "read" on a Shell script which reads its arguments from stdin

Tags: shell, cat, stdin, arguments

First of all, thank you for your help in advance and sorry in case this was answered before. I have not been able to find it.

For helping to understand my question, I have written the following simple script called "list_server_owners" (it is useless, but it is just an example):

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_LIST=""
SERVER_LIST="$(cat) " # This reads from stdin

for SERVER in $SERVER_LIST
    do
    echo -n "Please, write the server's owner: "
    read OWNER
    echo "${SERVER}'s owner is $OWNER"
    done
```

I have the following text file called "server_list":

```
Server1
Server2
```

And this is the output of the script passing "server_list" through stdin:

```
$ cat server_list | list_server_owner
Please, write the server's owner: Server1's owner is
Please, write the server's owner: Server2's owner is
```

The problem is easy to describe: the line of the script "read OWNER" is not working as I would like. The name of the server's owner is not being requested on the screen.

Do you know how I can make the command "read" request a string on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The file /dev/tty is a synonym for the controlling terminal of the process, so just redirect the input from that device:

```
...
read OWNER </dev/tty
...
```

You can also redirect the output of the echo prompt before to /dev/tty, and then be able to use the script in a pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read SERVER  # this reads from stdin
do
  echo -n "Please, write the server's owner: " >/dev/tty
  read OWNER </dev/tty
  echo "$SERVER:$OWNER"    # write to stdout
done
```

And use like:

```
 cat server_list | assign_owner > server_owner
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

You have to add do this:

```
MY_TTY=$(ps -ef | grep -m 1 $$ | awk '{print $6}')
read OWNER </dev/${MY_TTY}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, and it is the most simple for me:

```
exec 0</dev/tty
read OWNER
```

With this, you do not need to specify the standard input on all the "read" commands along the script.

I was confused becase, if you write the command "tty" inside of the script there is no output, but, as the last comment says (thank you), the special file /dev/tty is recognized.